# build a downloadable content in 3 columns

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I take responce from JSON and wanna to paste it in 3 columns. I'm using bootstrap class `col-md-4` and angularjs as framework.. I want to line up 3 elements in a row, but when content is too big - it breaks down and looks like :
[image]

See the following [plnkr (view in fullscreen)](https://plnkr.co/edit/fUEyQYIIxpPX8fOoTIaj?p=preview)

Comment: can use css3 flexbox instead of float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to place 3 columns infinitely inside a single row @ 992px or greater (col-md-4), simply clear the float of your columns at that media query.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .col-md-4:nth-child(3n+1) {
        clear: left;
    }
}
```

*Don't apply this directly to col-md-4 since it would then apply to that class globally.

**Clearing Column Floats Example**

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [{
    name: 'John1',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John2',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John3',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John4',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John5',
    text: ['asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas']
  }, {
    name: 'John6',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John7',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John8',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs', 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs', 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs', 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs', 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John9',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John10',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }]
})
```

```css
.grid-item-inner {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .grid-item:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item" ng-repeat="item in list">
        <div class="grid-item-inner">
          <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="thing in item.text track by $index">{{thing}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or if you're trying to place each column directly below one another (masonry layout), one way is with MasonryJS. See [Angular-Masonry](https://github.com/lucaslim/angular-masonry).

**AngularJS Directive for Masonry Example**

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('ngMasonry', [])
  .controller('masonryController', function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.config = {};
    vm.container = undefined;
    vm.ready = ready;
    vm.initialize = initialize;
    vm.reLayout = reLayout;

    function ready() {
      return !!vm.config && !!vm.config.masonryContainer;
    }

    function initialize() {
      var defaultOpts = {
          itemSelector: vm.config.masonryItem
        },
        opts = !vm.config.masonryOption ? defaultOpts : angular.extend(defaultOpts, vm.config.masonryOption);

      vm.container = new Masonry(vm.config.masonryContainer, opts);

      if (typeof imagesLoaded !== 'undefined') {
        new imagesLoaded(vm.config.masonryContainer, function() {
          vm.reLayout();
        });
      }
    }

    function reLayout() {
      vm.container.layout();
    }
  })
  .directive('masonry', function() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      controller: 'masonryController',
      compile: compile
    };

    return directive;

    function compile(element, attributes) {
      var flag = false,
        child = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('[' + attributes.$attr.masonry + '] [data-masonry-item], [' + attributes.$attr.masonry + '] [masonry-item]'));

      angular.forEach(child, function(obj) {
        obj = angular.element(obj);
        if (obj.attr('ng-repeat') !== undefined || obj.attr('data-ng-repeat') !== undefined) {
          flag = true;
          obj.attr('data-masonry-after-render', '');
        }
      });
      return {
        pre: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
          controller.config.masonryContainer = '[' + attributes.$attr.masonry + ']';
          controller.config.masonryOptions = JSON.parse(attributes.masonryOptions || '{}');
        },
        post: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
          if (!flag) {
            controller.initialize();
          }
        }
      };
    }
  })
  .directive('masonryItem', function() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '^masonry',
      priority: 1,
      compile: compile
    };

    return directive;

    function compile() {
      return {
        pre: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
          if (controller.config.masonryItem === undefined) {
            controller.config.masonryItem = '[' + attributes.$attr.masonryItem + ']';
          }
        }
      };
    }
  })
  .directive('masonryAfterRender', function($timeout) {
    'ngInject';
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: '^masonry',
      priority: 0,
      link: link
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attr, controller) {
      if (scope.$last) {
        var timeout = null;
        timeout = $timeout(function() {
          controller.initialize();
          $timeout.cancel(timeout);
        });
      }
    }
  });

//Your Code Starts Here

var app = angular.module('App', ['ngMasonry']);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [{
    name: 'John1',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John2',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John3',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John4',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John5',
    text: ['asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas', 'asdfasdfas']
  }, {
    name: 'John6',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John7',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John8',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs', 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs', 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs', 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs', 'asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John9',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }, {
    name: 'John10',
    text: ['asdfasdfasdfasdfasfsadfasdfsdfs']
  }]
})
```

```css
.grid-item-inner {
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .grid-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html data-ng-app="App">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" data-masonry>
      <div class="col-md-4 grid-item" data-masonry-item data-ng-repeat="item in list">
        <div class="grid-item-inner">
          <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="thing in item.text track by $index">{{thing}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.3.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/3.2.0/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**And generally speaking a Bootstrap Grid should use this pattern:

```
container or container-fluid
  row
    col-*-*
```

You currently have row followed by container. See [Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is bootstrap 3 uses floats, therefore in order for the columns to stay aligned correctly when they are different heights, you need to put a dummy clearfix in there.

[Bootstrap Clearfix](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)

An optional things you can do is also wrap every row in a 'row' lol. So in your case every three columns should be wrapped in their own div with a class of row.

Both these solutions produce problems in ng-repeat because you have to group your data by the number of columns you want and then nest the repeat again. Someone out there might have a better solution.

Like charlietfl suggested above, the least frustrating thing to do is use flexbox instead. You can write the css yourself or switch to bootsrap 4, but the catch is that support in IE is not the best.

You can also rewrite the columns css to use inline block instead of floats, but at that point what's the point of using bootstrap =P

```
.col-4 {
  width: 32%;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.col-4:nth-of-type(3n-1) {
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

[Like so](https://plnkr.co/edit/BN5AU7JVkexDp1ghsF4e?p=preview)