# How can I have a vertically stacked grid with as little JavaScript as possible

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Using an AngularJS ng-repeat I have a series of varying-sized divs that fill a page. The problem (as shown below) is that when I want an element to appear on a new line I want it to align the the element above it, while instead it aligns all the elements on this 'row' with the lowest-hanging element.

[image]

I am using Bootstrap, however I was at a loss on how to use the grid system to have data that could span any height per column. Instead all the divs are simply float: left'd with a max-width and a height: auto, which works to create a responsive left-aligned grid, but does not respect individual element placement per row.

For example, this grid would have the first element on the second 'row' (243 x 399) be a certain number of pixels below the first element on the first 'row' (224 x 305), with the certain number of pixels being a specified margin (though I'd be fine with it being flush with the element). Then 320 x 347 would be that same number of pixels below 344 x 246, and so on.

I know how I would go about doing this in Javascript/JQuery, though it'd definitely feel very hacky and I feel like there must be a more idiomatic way to achieve this goal using mostly CSS.

```js
var routeApp = angular.module('routerApp', []);
routeApp.controller('loadCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.tiles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * (400 - 200 + 1)) + 200;
      var e = Math.floor(Math.random() * (400 - 200 + 1)) + 200;
      $scope.tiles.push("http://placehold.it/" + d.toString() + "x" + e.toString());
    }
  }
]);
```

```css
.tiles {
  float: left;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="routerApp">
  <div ng-controller="loadCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="til in tiles track by $index">
      <a href="www.google.com"/>
        <img class="tiles" ng-src="{{til}}"/>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please post a **minimal working example** of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: The only clean of doing this is with flex-box but as you know it is not supported by all browsers. This article describes different css approaches but unfortunately they are all hacks. https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ . This is a jQuery plugin that I have used on multiple projects and it works very nicely. http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292914/build-a-downloadable-content-in-3-columns/38294455#38294455)

If that doesn't work out let me know I can try to elaborate more.

*Basically floats are like trying to patch a leak with scotch tape. =)*

Answer (score 0):

> The column-width CSS property suggests an optimal column width.

If you want a CSS only solution you can use the [column-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-width) and [column-gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap) (possibly [column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) as well) properties to create your grid.

**Make sure to check *[Caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/)* for Browser Support Info:**

1. [column-width](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-width)
2. [column-gap](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-gap)
3. [column-count](http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count)

**Example CSS**

```
.grid {
    -moz-column-width: 200px;
    -webkit-column-width: 200px;
    column-width: 200px;
    -moz-column-gap: 0;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    column-gap: 0;
    -webkit-perspective: 1
}

.grid .grid-block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid .grid-block .tiles {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**Example 1: Flush Columns** - Run Snippet at *FullPage*

```js
var routeApp = angular.module('routerApp', []);

routeApp.controller('loadCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.tiles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * (400 - 200 + 1)) + 200;
      var e = Math.floor(Math.random() * (400 - 200 + 1)) + 200;
      $scope.tiles.push("http://placehold.it/" + d.toString() + "x" + e.toString() + "/000/fff");
    }
  }
]);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
}
.grid {
  -moz-column-width: 200px;
  -webkit-column-width: 200px;
  column-width: 200px;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  column-gap: 0px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1
}
.grid .grid-block {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid .grid-block .tiles {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid teal;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.grid .grid-block .tiles:hover {
  opacity: 0.45;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body ng-app="routerApp">

  <div ng-controller="loadCtrl" class="grid">
    <div ng-repeat="tile in tiles track by $index" class="grid-block">
      <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <img class="tiles" ng-src="{{tile}}" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.js"></script>
```

**Example 1: Columns with Space** - Run Snippet at *FullPage*

```js
var routeApp = angular.module('routerApp', []);

routeApp.controller('loadCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.tiles = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      var d = Math.floor(Math.random() * (400 - 200 + 1)) + 200;
      var e = Math.floor(Math.random() * (400 - 200 + 1)) + 200;
      $scope.tiles.push("http://placehold.it/" + d.toString() + "x" + e.toString() + "/008080/000");
    }
  }
]);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 3px;
}
.grid {
  -moz-column-width: 200px;
  -webkit-column-width: 200px;
  column-width: 200px;
  -moz-column-gap: 6px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 6px;
  column-gap: 6px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1
}
.grid .grid-block {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid .grid-block .tiles {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.grid .grid-block .tiles:hover {
  opacity: 0.45;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body ng-app="routerApp">

  <div ng-controller="loadCtrl" class="grid">
    <div ng-repeat="tile in tiles track by $index" class="grid-block">
      <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <img class="tiles" ng-src="{{tile}}" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.2/angular.js"></script>
```